# How to Solve Python Mqtt Subscribtion Problem

Tags: python, excel, mqtt, paho

I want to write my datas which is coming from MQTT subscribtion to an excel page. The problem is that ı can only one time able print shared data from mqtt host. After first data my code is stopped and it required to run again. I could not understand the problem

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttclient
import time

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("client is connected")
        global connected
        connected=True
    else:
        print("connection failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global MessageReceived
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload.decode()))
    MessageReceived = True

#mqtt broker codes:
connected=False
MessageReceived = False

mqtt_port = 1883
mqtt_broker = "onurgonullu.cloud.shiftr.io"
mqtt_username = "onurgonullu"
mqtt_password = "12345"

client = mqttclient.Client("MQTT")
client.username_pw_set(mqtt_username,password=mqtt_password)
client.on_connect=on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(mqtt_broker,port=mqtt_port)
client.subscribe("ADC1")
client.loop_start()

while connected!=True:
    time.sleep(0.2)

while MessageReceived!=True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

When ı run the code it just work first time after, ıt does not work, ıt is stopped

Comment: Use `loop_forever` instead of `loop_start` and remove the while-loops.